# FPGA I2C master not working

Tags: fpga, vhdl, i2c, quartus, modelsim

I have written an I2C master for the DE10-Nano FPGA which is meant to communicate with the SSD1306 OLED display driver.

The issue I'm having is that it simply is not working when I actually test it on hardware. According to my debug lights the slave (SSD1306) is not sending the ack signal after receiving its address causing the master to go back to the 'idle' state. I know its the correct address (0x3C/0b00111100) because when I use the same address to control this display with an Arduino it works just fine.

I was wondering if anyone who is familiar with I2C could look at my waveforms and check for any glaring mistakes. The DE10-Nano has a 50 MHz clock which is down sampled to 10 KHz for the scl signal. I've also made sure to only change sda when scl is low and made sure I'm meeting all the timing requirements of the I2C spec.

sda goes low:

[image: sda goes low to start transmition]

- scl starts after sda has been low for 5 clock cyles (10 Khz)
- Ack state where cursor is checks if sda is pulled low (code was edited to pull low for the sim, would normally be set to 'H' so the slave can pull it low its self)

[image]

Another thing to note is that I'm supplying the SSD1306 with 3.3 V and the sda and scl pins are 3.3 V. When this display is working on the Arduino the sda and scl pins are 5 V as well as the supply but I know the display is able to operate with a 3.3 V supply.

If anyone wants to see any part of the VHDL I will post it.

Comment: Do you have a way to observe the signals between the FPGA and the screen to verify that the pins are well mapped ?

Comment: @BEN I don't have any such tool.

Comment: The start sequence in your second diagram looks wrong, there is a stop condition when `PresentState` changes from `start sequence` to `transmit address`. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the wrong address.

The address is 0x3C in 7-bit notation without R/W bit, which Arduino uses.

The address is 0x78 in 8-bit notation including R/W bit, which you use.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This doesn't seem to have fixed the problem as it still reverts back to the idle state instead of going to the transmit data state. But this does clear up the confusion I had about the address that worked for Arduino being different from the address that was listed in the data sheet of the SSD1306.

Comment: I'm now thinking about if the SSD1306 is able to drive the sda line low. As soon as it enters the check acknowledge state the code sets the sda line to 'H' or high pull-up which should allow it to be driven low externally.

Comment: @IanRider Are you sure you're setting your SCL output to open-collector, not push-pull? If it's push-pull, the slave device may be unable to pull the line low for the ACK.

Comment: @DoxyLover AFAIK the SCL line is not pulled low for ACK, but for clock stretching. The SDA line is pulled low for ACK.

Comment: @busybee you and DoxyLover are talking about different things now. The point was that both SDA and SCL must not be in push-pull but in open-drain mode, and during ACK the master must not pull SDA low so the slave can do it.

Comment: Justme, @thebusybee, if no slave devices are using clock stretching, and the vast majority don't use it, then an SPI master can safely use a push-pull driver for SCL and an open-drain for SDA. The benefit is a better SCL waveform, especially with a long or split bus. Have used that on many systems.

Comment: So every time the sda or scl line has a logic high on it my code sets them to 'H' or 'weak pull-up'. Does that make them open drain? I'm confused how else to make a pin open drain if driving logic highs as a pull-up and driving logic lows as a strong '0'.

Comment: @TonyM ^^^^^^^^

Comment: @IanRider Well according to your diagram the FPGA does set SDA high but I don't know how you should set it to not push strongly high, only weakly. Weak pull-ups might also be too weak, which is why normally you would use external resistors in the order of 2k to 10k. Typically no one should use e.g. MCU built in pull-ups either, for same reason. And while TonyM is technically right that sometimes SCL can be a push-pull output, it's against the specs and spirit of I2C.

Comment: @Justme, actually old son, it's smack on the specs of I2C, specifically UM10204 (I used v3.0 but see any other) **3.1 SCL and SDA signals** *For a single controller application, the controller’s SCL output can be a push-pull driver design if there are no devices on the bus which would stretch the clock.* Rest easy that the spirit of I2C is sparkling clean and unblemished :-)

Comment: @IanRider, a push-pull driver has an upper transistor and lower transistor. For open-drain, the upper transistor is always off, replaced externally by a resistor or by the internal pull-up in your FPGA/CPLD. In VHDL, for pin 'SCL' driven by internal control DFF output 'sclDrive', that's:  *SCL <=  'Z'  when (sclDrive = '1') else  '0';*

Comment: @TonyM Well that's amazing, I often do consult the latest native I2C specs but never realized it is allowed from V3 onwards introduced in 2007. Originally it was not allowed. And I guess the reason I haven't noticed that is I never made a multimaster design and only a handful of chips have ever used clock stretching. But I mainly work with buses that derive from I2C, where support for clock stretching is mandatory, as they base on the I2C standard version 2.1.

Comment: @Justme, v2.1 says *"The output stages of devices connected to the bus must have an open-drain or open-collector to perform the wired-AND function"* and SCL with no stretching isn't a wired-AND function, it's just driving inputs. But that's really me toying with the wording. To be honest though, it's always been clear it could be done electrically, for benefits with no downsides, so I think v3.0+ just spelt it out. Another SCL driver pin scheme is to drive SCL high with limited current briefly on a rising edge then tri-state it, to speed its rising edge like on PCI, 8051 I/Os and loads more.